# python: use await in async and run in browser

Tags: python, telethon

I use this code in python

```
import webbrowser
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from threading import Timer
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from aiohttp import web

api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def hello(request):
    client.start()
    #me = await client.get_me()
    return web.Response(text = "Hello")

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', hello)
web.run_app(app)
```

After I run `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` in browser, printed `hello`

But if I remove `#` and use me = await client.get_me() in my code, I get error :

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
  client.start()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I want below code work:

```
async def hello(request):
    client.start()
    me = await client.get_me()
    return web.Response(text = "Hello")
```

Comment: You should start your client in your main and keep it alive for the whole time.

Comment: @LtWorf. thank you. Can you help me more? I want run `client` and use `client.get_me()` every refresh the page.

Comment: Then start the client and just call the get_me when you need it, don't call start all the time, it probably makes it slow.

Comment: As a side note, you seem to have `from threading import Timer`. This will generally interact poorly with `asyncio`, and is better if you avoid it. With `asyncio` you can `create_task` with a loop and `sleep` that achieves the same.

Comment: @Lonami i used `client.connect()` after `client.start()` and worked fine